# Xpages djCurrencyTextBox with fractional=false

Tags: dojo, xpages

Since clean 8.5.3 Domino has problem with localized numbers with space as thousand separators, I decided to switch to djCurrencyTextBox. But as don't want to display fractional part, I'm struggling with it too. Even on 9.0.1 test server.

If I create simple field using:

```
<xe:djCurrencyTextBox id="djCurrencyTextBox1" value="#{document1.currency}">
  <xe:this.constraints>
      <xe:djNumberConstraints fractional="false">
      </xe:djNumberConstraints>
  </xe:this.constraints>
</xe:djCurrencyTextBox>
```

It does not recognize any number entered. ( I get message that value is not valid even when I enter just 1)

When add it as dojo attribute directly, it works as expected

```
<xe:djCurrencyTextBox id = "djCurrencyTextBox1"
         value ="#{document1.currency}" >

         <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
             <xp:dojoAttribute name ="data-dojo-props"
                     value ="constraints:{fractional:false}" >
            </xp:dojoAttribute>
         </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
</xe:djCurrencyTextBox >
```

Any ideas what can cause the issue?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're really trying to achieve, but just implementing both your code samples I get exactly the same result against a 9.0.1 server: the input only allows me to enter a number using locale-based standard patterns like #.###,00 (German locale in my case). Everything else is showing me dojo's yellow warning sign

Comment: I just needed a number without fractional part as we almost don't use it anymore here in Czech rep. But as Brian noted bellow, it is know bug and we have to live with it for some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue that is not fixed in 9.0.1

Using the first example above, no matter what value you set on the fractional constraint (enable/disable/auto/true/false), the textbox only ever accepts a value with fractional part included (e.g. 567.89), which is incorrect for disable & false values. The second example works as expected with fractional set to true or false.

This is because, looking at the page source, the html output for the first example is:

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.CurrencyTextBox" constraints="{&quot;fractional&quot;:&quot;false&quot;}" id="view:_id1:djCurrencyTextBox1" name="view:_id1:djCurrencyTextBox1">
```

The "`&quot;`" parts should not be included in the constraints.

Whereas with the 2nd example, there is no such issue:

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.CurrencyTextBox" data-dojo-props="constraints:{fractional:false}" id="view:_id1:djCurrencyTextBox2" name="view:_id1:djCurrencyTextBox2">
```

As this has not yet been fixed in 9.0.1, all you can do is utilise the workaround that you have posted for the time being.

**UPDATE**: The fix for this issue is in [Release 9 of the v901 XPages Extension Library on OpenNTF](http://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/releases/FC420BE9BF48AE3C86257D4D0033007F)

Comment: Thanks, is notes those &quot; symbols in source and wondered, what I did wrong. I can live with the workaround until IBM fixes it.

Comment: Update for you. This issue has been tracked since you raised it as SPR#JSHN93UT38.

The fix for it is likely to go into the next OpenNTF Extension Library release, version 901v00_09, which does not yet have a release date.

Comment: Updated my answer above as this has been fixed in Release 9 of the XPages Extension Library